# "On the order" vs "of the order"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

When we are trying to indicate the date or order quantity, do we use "on" an order or "of" an order?

> 1. Change the date on/of an order
> 2. Update the order quantity on/of an order

Since the order quantity belongs to the order, shouldn't we use "of" instead of "on?" I often hear people use "on" over "of."

Can someone explain the difference between "of" and "on" and how each is used?

I know we can also say:

> 1. An order of ten items.
> 2. Ship date of 3/22

Please critique if any of the above is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "Change the quantity of an order", it means to change the quantity of the idea of the order.

When you say "Change the quantity on an order", it would usually mean that the order is a physical object, such as a piece of paper with an order written on it.

It's the same thing for changing the date. Using "of" instead of "on" would be correct for both of these scenarios, so I would recommend using "of".

Comment: Thanks for your response. I meant to ask about the use of "changing the order quantity of an order," not the quantity of orders, if this makes sense. Is it correct, then, to say "change the order quantity of an order" instead of replacing "of" with "on?"

Comment: Yes, it would be correct to say "change the order quantity of an order"